# Select and remove data from database table and html using javascript/jquery without assign the div an ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to

- select all the rows from a specific table in database

and

- create a few divs with that specific data

without assigning them an `id` and then creating a `.delete-btn` to delete using javascript/jquery the specific `div` of the `.post` + deleting also in the database the specific row?

After selecting the data in database, then some divs post be creating like that:

```
<div class="newsFeed">
    <div class="post"> <!-- row #1 from DB -->
        <div class="author">Author name</div>
        <div class="text">Text...</div>
        <div class="time">time...</div>
        <div class="delete-post">
            <button type="button" class="delete-btn">delete this post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post"> <!-- row #2 from DB -->
        <div class="author">Author name</div>
        <div class="text">Text...</div>
        <div class="time">time...</div>
        <div class="delete-post">
            <button type="button" class="delete-btn">delete this post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post"> <!-- row #3 from DB -->
        <div class="author">Author name</div>
        <div class="text">Text...</div>
        <div class="time">time...</div>
        <div class="delete-post">
            <button type="button" class="delete-btn">delete this post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post"> <!-- row #4 from DB -->
        <div class="author">Author name</div>
        <div class="text">Text...</div>
        <div class="time">time...</div>
        <div class="delete-post">
            <button type="button" class="delete-btn">delete this post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When clicking the `.delete-btn` the `.post` (parent div) and the `row` from the `database` must be `deleted` also.

Is it possible? I mean I don't want to assign them an `id` (of the divs) because probably users can change the `id` of the `div` via [inspect element] and try to delete another post with that specific `id`.

EDIT:

Want exactly I want, is, after selecting the rows from database and create the divs, how can I find the ID of each div is creating in order to make a function in javascript to delete that specific div+row in database, knowing the ID.

Comment: yes - this is possible. but you need multiple technologies. 
you would need something like php to build the connection to the database and can than use javascript to trigger the given routes. you should have a look into the framwork vue-cli

Comment: No, i just want to know the javascript part how you get the correct ID of the specific div that was created in order to delete it. I know how to make a connection to db.

Comment: You need **some** way to tell your back-end which data to create/edit/delete.  That will need to be within the html, so will be editable by the end-user.   Using GUIDs may help as it's easy to change `data-id=123` to `data-id=124` but changing to another matching GUID would not be "guessable".  Or you could use index-based (eg 4th row).

Comment: or you could use some reactive framework like vue or react. this will keep track of the connection between storage and dom. but as @freedomn-m already mentioned - make sure the IDs are not easily faked.

Comment: As @MaZoli suggests, I would imagine a data-driven framework wouldn't need to have the database-id within the HTML as it would be in-memory.  Still needs to get in-memory somehow, so your user could be watching the network tab - but wouldn't be changeable via inspect element.

Comment: A possible alternative would be to match a server-side generated token, eg `<div data-id="123" data-token="abc">` then POST both the id and the token and validate them both - so if they changed to data-id=345 they wouldn't know what the token was so would fail server-side.